# How to compare two columns of a HTML (or XML) file, looking for number differences?

Tags: html, xml, comparison

As a English to French translator, I can create a bitext of my work, **which is a file with 2 columns**, the English on one side and the French on the other. These bitexts can either be in HTML of XML format. I am looking for a way to quickly compare these two columns in order to see any number differences.

Here is an example of what a bitext looks like

[image: example of a bitext].

Does a small program exist that can do that?

Thanks,

Mary-Jane

Comment: What do you mean by "number differences" ?

Comment: Is this on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for example use [Notepad++](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/notepad-compare-two-files.html) (needs an extra plugin) or [VSCode](https://vscode.one/diff-vscode/) which can do this natively.

Notepad++ is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how your XML/HTML looks like - would assume your texts are already organized/mapped into "rows"/"lines" per language/"column", and not the texts in the two languages as two consecutive, long text sequences, right?

Then, doesn't HTML allow to show these nicely as a HTML table? If not, if the source is a clean XHTML or XML source, could it easily be transformed into an HTML table (or CSV, to be viewed in LibreOffice Calc or Gnumeric)?

Otherwise I also generated PDFs as a "comparison table" ("[Synopse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synopse)", or for direct/literal word mapping there's [interlinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss)), or otherwise would just make a simple tool or online service, if the sources aren't too complex.

Diff tools might not be an option, because these assume you have the texts in two separate files, and the lines are mostly matching/mapping.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).